# NextJS 14 returns old cached data even if external API returns error on revalidate

Tags: next.js

**Description :**

1. I have a API route handler `ping`, which gets data from external API. This external API is an mock API(made using Mockoon Tool) which returns random statuses like 200, 404, 429, 503 after it gets HIT.
2. I have applied `next: { revalidate: 10 }` & `export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'` in my API route handler, & also added console.logs to see response statuses.
3. When I HIT this API route handler `http://localhost:3000/api/ping` from ThunderClient it returns data from cache. Even if external API sends error statuses (visible in Mockoon Tool logs).
4. It never caches error statuses (404, 429, 503) but after getting a 200 status response, it just ignores every error response given by external API.
5. If I remove `next: { revalidate: 10 }` it works but, HITs external API everytime for each request which is basically not what I want.

> NextJS Version : "14.1.4"

**Current Behavior :**

> API route handler returns old cached data (which has status 200) even if external API gives error status(404, 429, 503).

**Expected Behavior :**

> I want this API route handler to return cached data(whatever it is error or data) if revalidation time is remaining, else fetch fresh data & return it as it is *(whatever it is error or data)*.

[image]

**API Route Handler Code :**

```
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export async function GET() {
    try {

        console.log("PING : ", new Date().toLocaleTimeString())

        let res = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/ping`,
            {
                method: "GET",
                next: { revalidate: 10 }
            })

        let data = await res.json()
        console.log("DATA : ", data);

        if (!res.ok) {
            console.log("Not OK", res.status);
            return NextResponse.json({ error: data.error }, {
                status: res.status,
                statusText: res.statusText
            })
        }
        else {
            console.log("OK", res.status);
            return NextResponse.json({ ...data }, {
                status: res.status,
                statusText: res.statusText,
            })
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log("Error");
        return NextResponse.json({ error: e.toString() }, {
            status: 500,
            statusText: "Internal Server Error"
        })
    }
}
```

**So where should I update code, what should I do to by which I can cache external API responses as it is ?**

**Helpful Links :**

- Route Segment Config : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config